# Firebase 3: Ambiguous use of 'observeEventType(_:withBlock:)'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To rule out a project issue, I created a brand new single view project and added the following podfile:

```
target 'App' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

I then added the following code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        ref.observeEventType(.Value) { (snapshot) in

        }
    }   
}
```

The result is the following error:

> Ambiguous use of 'observeEventType(_:withBlock:)'

with:

> Found this candidate (FirebaseDatabase.FIRDatabaseReference)
>
> Found this candidate (FirebaseDatabase.FIRDatabaseReference)

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and the podfile.lock is as follows:

```
PODS:
  - Firebase (3.3.0):
    - Firebase/Core (= 3.3.0)
  - Firebase/Analytics (3.3.0):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (= 3.2.1)
  - Firebase/Core (3.3.0):
    - Firebase/Analytics (= 3.3.0)
  - Firebase/Database (3.3.0):
    - Firebase/Analytics (= 3.3.0)
    - FirebaseDatabase (= 3.0.2)
  - FirebaseAnalytics (3.2.1):
    - FirebaseInstanceID (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
    - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.3)
  - FirebaseDatabase (3.0.2):
    - FirebaseAnalytics (~> 3.2)
  - FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.7)
  - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.1):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
  - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.1)
  - GoogleUtilities (1.3.1):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - Firebase
  - Firebase/Database

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Firebase: 6250071f0e2440a5c4c67b8cb6b868f868237ac3
  FirebaseAnalytics: 0fd6532cb2c3d03cd5cf26ad295ccb091efd3104
  FirebaseDatabase: 59bea2e7dfd81b3b8b2f8e396caf1a52c2ced6f7
  FirebaseInstanceID: a9d923f3d0b6fbf9fac89310860357aaadc34be5
  GoogleInterchangeUtilities: def8415a862effc67d549d5b5b0b9c7a2f97d4de
  GoogleSymbolUtilities: 33117db1b5f290c6fbf259585e4885b4c84b98d7
  GoogleUtilities: 56c5ac05b7aa5dc417a1bb85221a9516e04d7032

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 261a8ee435b8325808d7a0962ace0c908fd37368

COCOAPODS: 1.0.1
```

Same issue with `observeSingleEventOfType(_:withBlock:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like it's a [Swift bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1338), try to use this syntax instead (without trailing closure syntax.):

```
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { firDataSnapshot in

})
```

More info: [Ambiguous use of 'observeSingleEventOfType(_:withBlock:)' error in Swift](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/iMJQ01KZBBA)

Comment: Yep that solved it! Weird one... When I threw in a print statement it compiled ok but any other code in the closure would throw the error... Thanks!

Comment: @doovers I've been there :/